# Post a dynamic template array to ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I would like to post array of dynamic object to elastic search. If I post a single object all the fields would be visible correctly but if I use an array I see only a single field with stringified version of Array.

````
```
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
const client = new elasticsearch.Client();
const bodyMsg = [
  { index: { _index: 'logs-2018.04.09', _type: 'log', pipeline: null } },
  {
    '@timestamp': '2018-04-09T12:17:17.645Z',
    message: 'logmessage1',
    severity: 'info',
    fields: {
      temp:
        {
          testKey: 'testValue',
        }
    }
  }];

client.bulk({
  body: bodyMsg,
  waitForActiveShards: this.waitForActiveShards,
  timeout: '10ms',
  // type: this.type
}).then((res) => {
  if (res.errors && res.items) {
    res.items.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.index && item.index.error) {
        console.error('Elasticsearch index error', item.index.error);
      }
    });
  }
})
```
````

for above piece of code I do get the object posted to elasticsearch as `fields.temp.testKey` with value as `testValue`.
But if I use an array for fields i.e.

````
```
    fields:  {
      temp:
        [{
          testKey: 'testValue'
        }]
    }
```
````

then on ES I see key `fields` with value `temp[{  testKey: 'testValue' }]`, but what I expect is something like below:
`fields.temp[0].testKey` with value `testValue1` and `fields.temp[1].testKey` with value `testValue2` and so on.

My dynamic template is:

````
```
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": { "enabled": false, "omit_norms": true },
      "_source": { "enabled": true },
      "_ttl": { "enabled": true, "default": "900d" },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "keyword",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "text", "index": true, "omit_norms": true,
              "fields": {
                "raw": { "type": "keyword", "index": true, "ignore_above": 256 }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date" },
        "@version": { "type": "keyword" },
        "message": { "type": "text", "index": true },
        "severity": { "type": "keyword", "index": true },
        "fields": {
          "type": "object",
          "dynamic": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```
````

Please suggest how to handle array when posting to ES ?

Answer (score 0):

Each document needs to be a new element of the array

```
[indexDef, item1, item2, item3 ... itemx]
```

An example of adding two documents would be:

```
[
  { index: { _index: 'logs-2018.04.09', _type: 'log', pipeline: null } },
  {
    '@timestamp': '2018-04-09T12:17:17.645Z',
    message: 'logmessage1',
    severity: 'info',
    fields: {
      temp:
        {
          testKey: 'testValue',
        }
    }
  },
{
    '@timestamp': '2018-04-09T12:17:17.645Z',
    message: 'logmessage2',
    severity: 'info',
    fields: {
      temp:
        {
          testKey: 'testValue2',
        }
    }
  }];
```

You will need to add `@timestamp` `severity` and `fields` to every element in your array.

Or if you are looking to store an array inside a document and lookup a value from that array directly just insert one document

```
{
    '@timestamp': '2018-04-09T12:17:17.645Z',
    message: 'logmessage1',
    severity: 'info',
    fields: {
      temp:
        {
          values: [
            testKey: 'testValue';
           ]
        }
    }
  }
```

That can be accessed via `temp.values[0].testKey`

However I'm not sure how this is indexed... normally each key would be put in a separate document.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I need to post in a single message with Array `fields`. Is that something not possible with ES ?

Comment: So it is one entry with multiple fields?  I'm not sure I understand what outcome you are trying to achieve

Comment: Yes it is one entry with Array or multiple fields. I basically need to see the key value pairs in ES something like this : `fields.temp[0].testKey` with value `testValue1` and `fields.temp[1].testKey` with value `testValue2` and so on.

Comment: hrm.  not sure what you want is possible as fields are just object indexes, I've updated the answer above with a possible solution where you store an object that contains an array i.e. `fields.temp.values[0].testkey`